# why we use ternary operator instead of if else statement

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

// contract AgeVerifier{
//     function checkEligibility(uint256 _age) public pure returns (bool) {
// if ( _age >=18 ) {
// return true;

// } else {
// return false;
// // Execute this code if _number is not 0
// }
//     }
// }

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract AgeVerifier {
    function checkEligibility(uint256 _age) public pure returns (bool) {
        return (_age >= 18 ? true : false);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's just for readability and simplicity. We can call it syntactic sugar.

Comment: Note that this particular code example is bad as one can simply write `return _age >= 18`

Answer (score 0):

temporary operator is simplified type of "If Else" command.
So you can write if else instead temporary operator.
This depends on developer's opinion